# One table or multiple tables for data having only one column change

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have four types of data's in a SQL Server Database Table: *forum topic*, *article topic*, *chat topic* and *QnA Topic*. These have same type of columns : `ID`, `Title`, `Content`, `User`,`type` etc. The only difference is the `type` column that is used to detect if the current content is *forum topic*(`type` = 0) or *article topic*(`type` = 1) and so on.

My colleagues said it will be better to store them in separate tables namely `ForumTopics`, `Articles`, `Chats`, `QnAs`. But in my view its not a good idea because the C# methods that are based on these content will be different and either I have to write multiple functions having same logic for each operation for each table or a conditional check in one function that its a *forum topic*(`type` = 0) or *article topic*(`type` = 1) or other.

Please tell me which is a better approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One table is better approach because it will give you flexibility in the future. You will be able to do things like the following:

- Select everything for a particular user
- Search something in all titles

Besides multiple tables are harder to maintain and you are right. There will be more complexity and repetition in your C# code as well with multiple tables.

Answer (score 1):

Using one table is better way because it is difficult to maintain data if it is stored in separate table you have to write complex queries.
If you use multiple table you have to use joins or subquery to retrieve data which makes slow performance.

So go with a single table.